# How to get Smith normal form of a matrix

Tags: matrices, smith-normal-form

I have the following matrix

$$m=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

How does one compute the Smith normal form of this matrix?

Comment: Welcome to mathstack exchange. It will help others to note what you have tried and where exactly you are having an issue.

Answer (score 0):

A series of row swappings yields
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&1\\0&-1&1&0\\0&0&-1&0 \\0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: i got diagonal matrix, but what to do next?

Comment: If it is diagonal and  each element in the diagonal divides the next one, it's finished.